# Why is Java automatically casting from String to Integer when reading LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, string, integer, classcastexception, linkedhashmap

My Java application is displaying some odd behaviour, and I'm having trouble finding a solution.

This code snippet takes the contents of a `LinkedHashMap` where the keys and values are both of type `String` and writes them to a text file. `configWriter` is of type `PrintWriter`.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : configMap.entireSet()) {

    configWriter.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

The map was declared:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> configMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

It is populated by reading tokens from a text file using the `Scanner` class.

One of the values in the map is a `String` that contains only numbers (an integer), but when the loop gets to this value, it throws a `ClassCastException` saying that you cannot cast from `Integer` to `String`. This makes perfect sense, but the type of the values is String.

Is there a way to force Java to keep this value as a `String`?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `configMap`?  This very much sounds like rawtypes got used somewhere and the map doesn't actually contain all `String`s.

Comment: Also, the stack trace might be helpful.

Comment: Edit the question, don't add info as comments.

Comment: Java isn't going to convert values for you--it's something in the code.

Comment: There could be a call to `configMap.putAll(someRawMap);` that's adding junk to your map

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill The stack trace won't help, because the `ClassCastException` only happens when you pull a value *out* of the map and try *use* it as a `String`.

Comment: Well, my view is that without the stack trace, we don't know precisely *where* the exception occurs. The behavior is a mystery, so the source of the exception may be surprising.

Comment: Wait, so how was the `Integer` sneaking in?

Comment: @PaulBellora I didn't realize, but this HashMap was also being populated from a JSON response in addition to the source I mentioned above. It turns out that the JSON parser I was using wasn't reading values in as Strings which I originally thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's almost certain that rawtypes are getting used somewhere and there's an `Integer` sneaking its way into the map.

The easiest way to identify *where* an `Integer` is getting inserted into the map is to replace the initialization of `configMap` with

```
Map<String, String> configMap = Collections.checkedMap(
  new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(), String.class, String.class);
```

which will actually throw an exception if something other than a `String` gets inserted into the map.  I wouldn't personally use that in production code, but this is probably the simplest way to "smoke out" the bug; you'll get an exception and a stack trace for where exactly the `Integer` is getting inserted.

As it stands, the way generics are implemented with type erasure means that there's nothing *actually* stopping non-`String` values from being inserted into the map.  The compiler makes some effort to prevent it, but rawtypes and legacy code can get around it.  Using `Collections.checkedMap` will force the issue, though.

Comment: Did you mean `Collections.checkedMap`?

Answer (score 2):

Louis Wasserman has explained the probable cause of your problems.

I just want to point out that there are a couple of flaws in your thinking in your question.

> Why is Java automatically casting from String to Integer when reading LinkedHashMap

First, you can't cast from a `String` to an `Integer`.  With Java reference types, you can only cast an object to a type if the object is an instance of that type, or a subtype of that type.  The `String` type is not a subtype of `Integer`, so the operational semantics of the JVM *forbid* such a cast - you'd get a runtime exception if you wrote compilable code that tried to do this.

Second, there is nothing in `LinkedHashMap` ... or any other collections class which would *convert* an element/key/value instance from `String` to `Integer` without you telling it to.  Well-behaved (Java) APIs just don't do that kind of thing.

Which brings us back to Louis's diagnosis - something (e.g. your code) has added that `Integer` object as a value.  It is the kind of thing that can happen if you use raw types or suppress / ignore "unchecked conversion" warnings.